# How to generate chart from excel sheet with macro

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I have got some data in excel sheet

```
id                                          X           Y
93c3ac0d-5618-42a1-8495-79c890bcc440    3,855860732 3,855888397
7ba28c26-2a1f-41be-80f0-b0cfae97c504    3,818260653 3,818589846
a23ace40-c3c3-45cc-ab32-b59e33b7f83b    9,55033235  9,58033235
013c91b3-bc88-4dbd-ba65-1b02fd093ebb    6,541669914 6,552391904
afaef874-f52c-4ba2-9565-8bc7facabc93    6,560388448 6,570680712
35bfd027-147d-4a18-aa1b-217a3593c4b0    8,532138865 8,550715203
2b7e96d4-8e7b-422b-b07e-0e75378777cd    8,541575561 8,53250362
d34f7be8-65d1-4c22-b4c7-344db0ba356b    8,542794004 8,545666996
9430ea31-f8da-43be-9a4f-54cf382aa450    8,557895658 8,522192019
30d1998a-85b2-456b-81a7-878eafc418f7    9,55033235  9,58033235
19876333-2120-445e-b1cf-d6f5503c8513    9,55033235  9,58033235
4831acb3-b9e3-4a4c-9619-c835f6e77ea2    9,55033235  9,52033235
47bc5691-a6af-4898-b892-da98b56e6f6f    6,54075573  6,544362052
e4ab1a50-26e5-4f0e-8d62-ab24249125e9    8,5416706   8,5559438
56e6298e-e05a-433e-8365-a97dba2276df    9,55033235  9,52033235
f550a46e-139d-4073-a30e-d9c37d807475    9,55033235  9,548071894
43c667e0-c505-4843-aead-cbfc32bf6ac4    3,828557425 3,828682676
18f4f9a7-dfba-4e39-8a9d-6e812dbf89f3    6,512208526 6,509076709
44065b42-342d-42b2-872c-15891cd8e8e6    8,549072661 8,565770097
dcd8497e-8cb0-4d3b-9f14-d4362cc42e4c    6,545840736 6,570819834
e7405709-e212-443e-81db-4f57cceca642    9,55033235  9,52033235
0d639735-175f-4a5d-980a-37032c26cd5f    6,544109632 6,543897064
30860a47-101e-4fdb-8e9c-33475a140029    3,816656205 3,817036757
49e58de1-c621-4d52-844a-13b93190e8ce    9,55033235  9,52033235
c6d085be-dcfd-42de-b084-fbf657c44175    6,545139879 6,544869008
```

How to create macro to process all visible rows adding to chart
now series (guids) with x and y values to point chart (`ChartType = xlXYScatter`)?
The result chart should be placed in new sheet and have 25 series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below will do the trick. 
Though I'm wondering why on Earth you would want each point in a separate series...

```
Option Explicit

Sub zonk()

    Dim i As Long

    With Charts.Add ' Make new chart
        ' Set its properties
        .ChartType = xlXYScatter
        .Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet
        .HasLegend = False

        ' Add the series
        For i = 1 To 25
            With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                .XValues = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1 + i, 2)
                .Values = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1 + i, 3)
                .Name = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1 + i, 1)
                ' Assuming your data is at the top left of Sheet1...
            End With
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Jean-François Corbett thanx for help. I need it because

Comment: ... I wrote implementation of GSO alghorithm and I would like to present agent placments at last iteration. Next I would like to present how agents moved so one segemnt presents one agent movemnt.

Comment: To get a dynamic link for the series name, use this: `.Name = "=" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1 + i, 1).Address(, , , True)`